# How to update UPS moduel of magento 1.6 to UPS Module of 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.6, ups

I am running Magento 1.6, Here UPS shipping module is not update, I mean it is not using userID, password and access key.

So I want to upgrade UPS module with latest one, But not want to upgrade entire magento project.

Please suggest, How I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to copy the complete usa extension from 1.9 as a local module and change the complete namespace to an own to avoid conflicts with the original one. This will be some work, ...

After that you can disable the original module in your local.xml.